# What is the recommended database management system and wrapper for python?

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We just want to save some arm poses/postures and base positions. For now we save these with couchdb. As we have to do some changes we want to find out whats currently the best and easiest database solution for ROS.

- We use ORK so we have a couchdb running anyway. But there no nice wrapper seems to be available?
- [mongodb_store](http://wiki.ros.org/mongodb_store) looks very pythonic and is currently our favourite. Any comments?
- The [python wrapper](https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros/blob/master/test/test_mongo_rospy.py) for warehouse_ros also looks promising but not as nice as mongodb_store. But perhaps warehouse is supported by more packages?
- What about relational databases?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210420/what-is-the-recommended-database-management-system-and-wrapper-for-python?/) by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2756 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We went for [mongodb_store](http://wiki.ros.org/mongodb_store) because it was the most pythonic solution.

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1